# Session timeout in Python

Tags: python, session, post, timeout, python-requests

Here is the code I am working with.

```
import requests

headers = { 'Accept':'*/*',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cookie':'Cookie:PHPSESSID=vev1ekv3grqhh37e8leu1coob1',
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Proxy-Authorization':'Basic ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q6ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q=',
            'If-Modified-Since':'Fri, 13 Nov 2015 17:47:23 GMT',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
            }


with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://172.31.13.135/tpo/spp/'
    c.get(url, headers=headers)
    payload = {'regno': 'myregno', 'password': 'mypassword'}
    c.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers)
    r = c.get('http://172.31.13.135/tpo/spp/home.php', headers=headers)
    print r.content
```

I get the following message when I run this script.

```
<script>
alert("Session timeout !");
window.location = "logout.php";
</script><script>
alert("Unauthorised Access!");
window.location = "index.php";
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

How do I deal with this "session timeout" issue ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just pass the timeout variable in your get and post method:

```
timeout = 10  # ten sec.
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://172.31.13.135/tpo/spp/'
    c.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    payload = {'regno': 'myregno', 'password': 'mypassword'}
    c.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    r = c.get('http://172.31.13.135/tpo/spp/home.php', headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    print r.content
```

You could tweak the max time you wan to wait for a response by doing this
For more about request see [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts)

Answer (score 1):

It really makes tough to answer when I can't visit the website to scrape.
So here's my guess,

1) Try removing cookies from your headers you don't need that.
Because `requests.Session()` will generate cookies of its own when you visit `url = 'http://172.31.13.135/tpo/spp/'` for the first time.

```
So your headers will be,

headers = { 'Accept':'*/*',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Proxy-Authorization':'Basic ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q6ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q=',
            'If-Modified-Since':'Fri, 13 Nov 2015 17:47:23 GMT',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
            }
```

2) Make sure that `'If-Modified-Since'` field in header is static to what you have mentioned and it doesn't change. If it does change then please code it accordingly to set the date and time on realtime basis.

3) I am not sure why you have `'Proxy-Authorization':'Basic ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q6ZWRjZ3Vlc3Q='` in headers. Try headers without it.
But, if you have to have it then please make sure that this auth code is static too and it doesn't change everytime.

Let me know if that helps